# n-to-n selector UI

Tags: gui-design, terminology

I am looking for a name of one specific UI element. I have unsuccessful tried to identify it before but this attempt failed.

What I am looking for is an n-to-n selector where items move between two states. Lets say you have two buckets (states), one on the left, one on the right. There are multiple items in the left bucket and you can move them to the right bucket and back.

What is the name of this element? How is it different from normal list where you can select multiple items?

Comment: [This url](http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/user-interface-elements.html) describe most of UI elements, also You can find a lot of information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Controls/Controls.html) or other similar guidelines

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The UI element you are referring to is called the **List Builder**

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742407.aspx#usage

> List builders allow users to create a list of choices by adding one item at a time, and optionally setting the list order.

[image]

> A list builder consists of two single-selection lists: the list on the left is a fixed set of options and the list on the right is the list being built. There are two command buttons between the lists:
>
> 1. An **Add button** that moves the currently selected option to the list being built, inserted before the selected item. (Double-clicking on an option item has the same effect.)
> 2. **A Remove button** that removes the selected item from the built list and returns it to the option list. (Double-clicking on an item in the built list has the same effect.) The built list may optionally have Move Up and Move Down commands to order the list items.

Comment: Great find. Didn't know this kind of interface had a name.

Answer (score 10):

I think you are looking for a list to list item selector. I used to work for SAP and in SAP world we used to call this "Browse & Collect" UI pattern. The only place i have seen this UI outside SAP is for selecting table columns to be shown.

Here's [a link](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/WDJava/Browse+and+Collect+using+Drag+and+Drop+in+WD+Java+CE+7.1) that talks more of this

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In Django it's called a 'FilteredSelectMultiple' widget some call it 'multi select widget'. But that is the name of the basic [html widget](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple) thats underneath. I think the **filtered** part is because of the search field in top of the left column. It works really nice and filters the left column when typing. It works great with long lists!

[image: FilteredSelectMultiple widget]

Comment: thanks, that is of great help, I finally managed to find this for Twitter Bootstrap http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/, they call it dual list box, but it has the filter at  the top which is important for me.

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek: The bootstrap-duallistbox has a `moveonselect` option. Items move to the other list on a single click or not at all. The Django FilteredSelectMultiple moves items on double click. Single click is just selecting an item. I don't know how others do that. I think single click is faster but with a double click users are less likely to make mistakes.