# What is the name of this design pattern?

Tags: interaction-design, input

What's the name of this pattern?

I have two lists side by side. The list on the left has all the possible options. The list on the right contains the selected options. There is a button like "add" or ">>" that copies the selected items on the left to the right side box. There is also a "<<" or "delete" button that removes the selected items on the right.

The >> button does not add duplicate items on the right hand side. That is, if a list item U is already in the right side (selected), hitting ">>" will not copy it over again.

What's this pattern called and is there a jquery plugin for it that runs on Iphones or Ipads?

Comment: Sounds like your question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852995/whats-this-ui-pattern-called).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can call it as **Drag & Drop functionality**.

However, this is more towards the functionality question than the ux related. Since you have asked that your requirement is for mobile then am not sure in what scenario you need such functionality. So, lets explore these few examples and let us know, is that what you are looking or something different.

Few examples;

1. http://www.akchauhan.com/select-content-from-one-list-to-another-using-jquery/
2. Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy7rT/6/)

Comment: JaganJ - exactly what I needed. A million votes up to you. :) I'd buy you a beer if I could. You saved me so much trouble.

Comment: I really don't think that the involvement of buttons can qualify for "drag & drop", or that "drag & drop" is an interaction technique limited to this "pattern"/widget...

Comment: @sidnioulz - I was considering that OP question on - mobile and tablet plugin where Button interaction is *NOT* necessary. However, if you see any cloud based file sharing apps on tablet these kind of functionality exists. It depends on the scenario and apps you can call this pattern as listbuilder or any other name.

Answer (score 11):

I've seen it called a [List Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_builder)

[image: A list builder]

This question I think is a duplicate of [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53029/n-to-n-selector-ui)

I wouldn't call it a "design pattern", but a commonly used interface element.

Comment: A design pattern is just an abstraction of commonly used elements.